# How do I fit a GLM in Julia while altering the max number of iterations?

Tags: julia

I am trying to fit a generalized linear model using Julia's GLM package. The fitting algorithm is failing because the max number of iterations, set by default to 30, is being exceeded. Examination of the source reveals that this parameter is stored as a named argument (`maxIter`) to the `fit` function, which is called at the end of the `glm` function if the `dofit` named argument to `glm` is `true` (which it is by default). So I should be able to adjust the max iterations by setting `dofit` to `false`, creating my glm, then calling `fit` manually on it with an altered `maxIter`:

```
myGlm = glm(formula, dataframe, Poisson(), dofit=false)
fit(myGlm, maxIter=50)
```

But the first line of this code fails with the error message:

> no method glm(Array{Any,1},Expr,DataFrame,Poisson,LogLink)

When I look at the function signatures for `glm` in the source (glmfit.jl) or with `help(glm)`, it's true that this signature isn't listed. But why is this the signature for my function call? Are named arguments automatically moved as an array to the beginning of the argument list, and do they need to be supported explicitly?  The source in the context of [This section of the Julia manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#named-arguments) suggests my call should work.

Comment: This does seem very odd. I think the easiest thing to do is to add a keyword argument to`glm` for `maxIter`, which you then pass to `fit` in the last line of `glm`. I suspect Doug will be happy to take a patch that adds that functionality.

Comment: @JohnMylesWhite Hmm, but there are three other keyword args to `fit`: `verbose`, `convTol`, and `minStepFac`. Adding only `maxIter` to `glmfit` might make the code more confusing, and adding all of the above seems unnecessarily repetitive. Is there a way to expand a Dict into keyword arguments in a function call? Then I could just add a keyword arg `fitoptions` to `glm` and pass it to `fit` in the last line of glm with `fit(res, fitoptions...)`. I know the `...` syntax won't work to expand a `Dict`, but is there a way?

Comment: Right now the only way is to pass in an arbitrarily large number of keywords using something like: `function glm(; kwargs...); fit(kwargs); end`. This basically produces a dict from all of the keyword args. I think we're still missing a useful abstraction here, but it probably won't be `Dict`'s since they aren't fully analyzable at compile time.

Comment: @JohnMylesWhite Thanks John. When I create a function `foo(; kwargs)` and look at `kwargs` inside the function, I see an Array of 2-tuples where the first elements are symbols (the keywords). I'm not sure how to access this like a `Dict`. Then, passing this array to another function (as in your `fit(kwargs)`) just passes it as a normal argument with no expansion. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the keyword arguments aren't being passed along in https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl/blob/master/src/glmfit.jl#L134

If that is so, you should file and issue, and in the meantime pass in a link function to the call so that the main `glm` function is called, not the convenience constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried `glm(formula,dataframe,Poisson(),LogLink(),dofit=false)` though and I'm getting the same error, which is strange because as you point out it seems like this should trigger the main glm function. I will file an issue.